# Postman body request with values from data file

Tags: postman

So i'm using postman, I have an URL that I can send POST request to, with a single json in the body where the key is "coupon" and the value is some number.

I want to run a test from postman that will place different numbers to the value of the coupon, and see all the responses that I will get.

I tried to read about the runner in postman, I figured that I can build a data file with all of the numbers for the coupon.

How can I replace the value in the post request with those numbers from the file data?

I'm trying to put a different number to this value, send it and get a response for each number.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkaNU.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: send it as raw data

Comment: But how I place it into the "value" of the json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the collection runner, load a CSV file that looks like:

```
value
123456
234567
345678
```

... and so on, one line for each coupon number. Then you replace the number in the key-value parameter editor with `{{value}}`. In the pre-request or test script, you could access it with `data.value`. See also [the Postman documentation on working with data files.](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files)